# How do I upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10 instead of 15.10?

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

When I run do-release upgrade on 14.04 it tries to upgrade me to 15.10. I completed it the first time but ran in to all sorts of mysql issues.

I reverted the snapshot and would like to try the incremental upgrades.

14.04
14.10
15.04
15.10

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Just in case you're not aware: 14.10 hit end-of-life on July 23, 2015

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to the question. Mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Go here:  http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.10/

Select the version you want (`ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso` or `ubuntu-14.10-desktop-i386.iso` etc) and download it.  Either burn it to disk or make bootable USB.

You can use `unetbootin` to create a bootable USB.  If not installed, do `sudo apt-get install unetbootin` in terminal to install it.

Boot from the CD or USB and select the option "Upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10" during the installation.

And just a tip before upgrading, run `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove` to clean things up before upgrading.  Just makes things smoother and the process a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke too soon. I chose the upgrade option and after reboot it seems to be running 14.10. Problem is that it destroyed everything I had installed. No more web server or any of the apps. I couldn't remember if I had used the server or desktop when originally built so I reverted the snapshot and started over. This time using the server ISO file. I don't even see an upgrade option in there.